# ckeditor full WYSWYG with embed objects

Tags: ckeditor, embed

I have a problem with CKEDITOR 4.x. We work a lot with embed objects: twitter, Facebook posts, VINE, Youtube etc. We need to user to be able to see the embed content.

For those using IFRAME, we just disable the iframe plugin and now the placeholder is gone. We are able to see exactly the content of the embed on the editor.

For those services using DIV + SCRIPT like FACEBOOK, we are unable to have a WYSWYG view on the editor. For example, this is a Facebook embed code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/gizmodo/posts/10153278450443967" data-width="500"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/gizmodo/posts/10153278450443967"><p>Everybody knows companies like Keurig and Nespresso really just want to sell you bad, wasteful coffee for over $50 a pound.</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gizmodo">Gizmodo</a> on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gizmodo/posts/10153278450443967">Friday, May 8, 2015</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

I believe the problem is the scripting is not working on the edit view.

Is there an issue way of doing this?

Comment: I encourage you to take a look on [CKEditor 4.5beta blog post](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Beta-Released); "Embedding Media" section, precisely.

Comment: I did, but is the same. Is much more 'easy' to add using a third party proxy, when once added, you don't see the exact content. Twitter and Facebook posts embed are the best examples.